# why isnt my code printing out the highest and 1st runner up properly?

Tags: java

Main:

```
public class Main {

  private static String [] Countries={"UK", "Italy",
            "Germany", "Thailand","Denmark","Japan","Spain","Argentina"};
  static double average[] = new double[8];
  double[] results = new double[8];

  public static String getWinner(ArrayList<MissUniverse>alist){
    int winner = 0;
    for (int s = 0; s < alist.size(); s++){
        if (alist.get(s).average() > alist.get(0).average() ) {
            winner= s;
        }
    }
    return alist.get(winner).getCountry();
  }

public static String firstRunnerUp(ArrayList<MissUniverse>alist){
    int firstrunnerUp =0;
    for (int s = 0; s < alist.size(); s++){
        if (alist.get(s).average() > alist.get(0).average() && alist.get(s).getCountry() != getWinner(alist) ) {
            firstrunnerUp = s;
        }
    }
    return alist.get(firstrunnerUp).getCountry();

  }

 public static void main (String[] args){
   ArrayList<MissUniverse> alist = new ArrayList<MissUniverse>();
 MissUniverse missUniverse[] = new MissUniverse[Countries.length];

        for(int i=0;i<Countries.length;i++)
        {
            missUniverse[i] = new MissUniverse(Countries[i]);
            missUniverse[i].getScore();
            alist.add(missUniverse[i]);
        }


   System.out.printf("%-15s%-5s%-5s%-5s%-5s%-5s%-5s%-5s%-5s%-10s",
                "Countries","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","Average");
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < Countries.length; i++){
    System.out.printf("%-13s",Countries[i]);
    missUniverse[i].printInfo();
    System.out.printf("%5.1f", alist.get(i).average() );
    System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("The result is");
    System.out.println("Winner: Miss " + getWinner(alist) );
    System.out.println("1st Runner Up: Miss " + firstRunnerUp(alist) );

  }
}
```

MissUniverse:

```
class MissUniverse { 
  public static int SIZE=8;
  private String country;
  private double[] score;  

  public MissUniverse(String country){
    this.country = country;
    score = new double [SIZE];
  }

  public String getCountry(){
    return country;
  }

  public void getScore(){
      for (int i=0;i<score.length;i++)
        {
            score[i] = Math.random()*10;
        }
  }

  public void setCountry(String newCountry) {
    this.country = newCountry;
  }

 private int highest(){
  int i;
        double highest;
        highest = score[0];

        for (i = 0; i <score.length; i++)
        {
            if (highest < score [i])
            {
                highest = score[i] ;
            }
        }
        return i;
  }

  private int lowest(){      
  int i;
        double lowest;
        lowest = score[0];
        for (i = 0; i <score.length; i++)
        {
            if (lowest > score [i])
            {
                lowest = score[i];
            }
        }
        return i;  
  }

  public double average(){

    double sum = 0.0;
     for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++){
        sum +=  score[i];
     }
    double average;
    average = (sum - score[lowest()-1] - score[highest()-1] )/ (score.length - 2);
    return average;
  }

  public void printInfo(){

      for(int i=0;i< score.length;i++){  
      System.out.printf("%-5.1f",score[i]);
      }

  }
}
```

Why is the output wrong?

output 1:

```
Countries      1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    Average   
UK           2.0  0.5  3.7  2.0  5.2  7.0  9.2  5.8    4.0
Italy        3.9  3.8  2.4  5.1  5.7  1.0  6.7  6.9    3.6
Germany      7.0  0.5  8.4  2.4  6.3  4.4  8.8  7.1    5.1
Thailand     6.9  8.7  3.9  4.7  4.9  3.5  4.7  9.4    4.7
Denmark      0.5  0.9  3.4  3.3  6.3  10.0 7.0  6.6    4.1
Japan        4.2  2.1  5.9  9.4  9.8  2.3  4.2  9.7    4.7
Spain        6.5  4.0  6.5  3.6  8.5  8.5  9.2  9.4    6.2
Argentina    0.4  6.6  6.5  2.3  2.6  4.5  5.6  3.7    4.1
The result is
Winner: Miss Argentina
1st Runner Up: Miss Spain
```

its supposed to be winner: miss spain, runner up: miss germany.
but isnt the logic in getWinner(alist) and firstrunnerup(alist) correct?

output 2:

```
Countries      1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    Average   
UK           0.5  9.2  2.8  1.3  7.0  9.6  6.9  6.9    5.1
Italy        4.3  7.6  2.3  3.3  8.6  9.3  7.0  3.1    6.5
Germany      2.2  0.4  6.1  4.4  5.8  3.1  5.5  9.1    3.1
Thailand     1.7  7.1  6.2  9.5  7.9  4.9  0.8  8.3    5.0
Denmark      1.6  1.6  2.5  6.5  8.8  5.8  3.7  1.2    4.9
Japan        7.4  1.5  5.6  1.6  3.1  5.8  3.2  3.4    4.1
Spain        0.2  0.9  0.3  7.2  1.5  7.8  7.3  8.6    2.7
Argentina    9.1  8.9  0.3  5.1  2.6  8.8  4.3  5.1    5.7
The result is
Winner: Miss Argentina
1st Runner Up: Miss Italy
```

its supposed to be:
winner:italy
runner up:argentina

can someone point me in the right direction?i think the mistake is supposed to be in the getwinner and firstrunnerup methods but i can't spot the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the compare condition.

Your compare condition for the winner is this `alist.get(s).average() > alist.get(0).average()` but it should be this `alist.get(s).average() > alist.get(winner).average()`. You should compare with the current winner.

Same goes for runnerup function, it should be this `alist.get(s).average() > alist.get(firstrunnerUp).average() && alist.get(s).getCountry() != getWinner(alist)`

Answer (score 1):

In getWinner() change

```
if (alist.get(s).average() > alist.get(0).average() ) {
```

to

```
if (alist.get(s).average() > alist.get(winner).average() ) {
```

Similarly in getFirstRunnerUp() change

```
if (alist.get(s).average() > alist.get(0).average() && alist.get(s).getCountry() != getWinner(alist) ) {
```

to

```
if (alist.get(s).average() > alist.get(firstRunnerUp).average() && alist.get(s).getCountry() != getWinner(alist) ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing wrong variables in `getWinner` and `firstRunnerUp`. Replace the functions with the following ones:

```
public static String getWinner(ArrayList<MissUniverse> alist){
    int winner = 0;
    double max = 0;
    for (int s = 0; s < alist.size(); s++){
        if (alist.get(s).average() > max) {
            max = alist.get(s).average();
            winner = s;
        }
    }
    return alist.get(winner).getCountry();
}

public static String firstRunnerUp(ArrayList<MissUniverse> alist){
    int firstrunnerUp = 0;
    double winner = 0;
    double max = 0;
    for (int s = 0; s < alist.size(); s++){
        if (alist.get(s).average() > max) {
            firstrunnerUp = winner;
            winner = s;
            max = alist.get(s).average();
        }
    }
    return alist.get(firstrunnerUp).getCountry();
}
```